# How do you secure user inputs going to an API in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do you secure user inputs going to an API in react native app? Like email, password, credit card etc

Is there any way I can implement ssl certificate on the client side? I'm new to mobile development sorry for my ignorance.

Do you have to encrypt the data before you send it to your API?

Thank you for all response really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your API has an SSL certificate and HTTPS activated, make your request with https from react-native. Your data will be automatically encrypted. You also have to ensure your API is secure, don't store plain text in your database, hash it before.